# the measurement problem, what is it that drives the wave function to collapse?

Tags: superposition, measurement-problem, decoherence, schroedingers-cat

I'm hearing a lot of different solutions to the measurement problem. But what is the right answer? Does consciousness play a role in the collapse of the wave function or is there a different factor at play.

I mean what counts as a measurement? is it a valid measurement if a quantum system is in a superposition of states and an unconscious person in coma is in the same room as that system, does the wave function collapse?

And if it doesn't would that imply that conscious beings can indeed collapse the wave function. Correct me if i'm wrong but wouldn't that mean that Schrödinger's famous 'cat in the box' thought experiment wouldn't work. Since cats are also conscious beings and therefor the described system couldn't form into a superposition in the first place. Or can a system form into a superposition whilst a conscious being is in the same room, but then when another being enters the room or 'observes' the system the wave function collapses?

And if consciousness doesn't play a role what is it that makes the wave function collapse? Is it decoherence interfering with the system and collapsing the wave function within a fraction of a second. Or is this only valid in the many-worlds or Everettian interpretation of quantum mechanics?

Comment: For Schrödinger's cat, the cat is not to be taken literally - one should rather think of something like a cat particle.

Comment: I thought the whole goal of the experiment was to show people how strange quantum mechanics was, and that the CH interpretation couldn't be quite right. Schrödinger tried to show this by proposing this thought experiment of a macroscopic object being in a superposition by a series of events. I think that's why the experiment got the attention it got, since people widely accepted that a particle could be in a superposition of states it wouldn't be a shocker that a 'cat particle' could also be in a superposition.

Comment: @DaanRijks What makes you think *consciousness* has anything to do with quantum measurements?

Comment: @Gert that's the exact thing i'm asking. Is a conscious being considered a measurer in quantum mechanics, or is it something else that's making the measurement? I think my question is; 'is consciousness creating reality as we know it? by constantly observing quantum systems around us and so giving rise to objects with a definite position in space by more local vibration in the associated fields.

Comment: @DaanRijks You do seem to be moving the goal posts all the time. Someone (better than me!) should first answer the question "*what is a quantum measurement?*"

Comment: @Gert I'm not moving any goal posts, i'm just clarifying what i'm exactly saying, for those who can't think an extra step ahead of what might be a possibility's after one thing is true or not. But I would indeed like the question "what is a quantum measurement?" to be answered.

Comment: @DaanRijks You don't think *by constantly observing quantum systems around us and so giving rise to objects with a definite position in space by more local vibration in the associated fields* is just a liiiittle bit outside the scope of your original question? Oh well...

Comment: @Gert Well Copenhagen says that when we are not observing a quantum system there is just a wave of probabilities, and ones this system is observed the wave function collapses and takes one definite postion in space. So if my question "is consciousness making the wave function collapse" is answered with a 'yes'. That would ultimately mean that when there are no conscious beings around to observe a system, it would be in a state of superposition. And then when consciousness comes in to the picture, it gets rid of the superposition states and gives rise to the world as we know it.

Comment: I don't think a conscious being is necessary to collapse the wavefunction. Do the double-slit experiment with a (non-conscious!) detector turned on and you will find no interference pattern even if there was no human present.